# Unresolve reference

Tags: android, kotlin

I´m new in this thing, I have used a tutorial as guide, I copy everything correct from the tutorial, but when I want to run the app I can´t because the following warnings appear:

```
Unresolved reference: isSuccesful
Unresolved reference: result
Unresolved reference: isSuccesful
Unresolved reference: result
Unresolved reference: FirebaseAuth
```

Here´s my code:

```
package com.mpdw55.medic_app

import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.firebase.analytics.FirebaseAnalytics
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_auth.*



class AuthActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_auth)

    // Analytics Event
    val analytics:FirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this)
    val bundle = Bundle()
    bundle.putString("message", "Integracón de Firebase completa")
    analytics.logEvent("Initscreen", bundle)

    //setup
    setup()
}

private fun setup(){

    title = "Autenticación"

    signUpButton.setOnClickListener {
        if (emailEditTest.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {

            FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditTest.text.toString(),
                    passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {}

            if (it.isSuccesful) {
                showHome(it.result?.user?.email?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)

            } else {
                showAlert()

            }

        }
    }

       logInButton.setOnClickListener {
           if (emailEditTest.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {

               FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
                   .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditTest.text.toString(),
                       passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {}

               if (it.isSuccesful) {
                   showHome(it.result?.user?.email?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)

               } else {
                   showAlert()

               }

           }
       }

}

private fun showAlert() {

    val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    builder.setTitle("Error")
    builder.setMessage("Se ha producido un error autenticando al ususario")
    builder.setPositiveButton("Aceptar", null)
    val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
    dialog.show()
}

private fun showHome(email: String, provider: ProviderType){

    val homeIntent = Intent(this, HomeActivity::class.java).apply {
        putExtra("email", email)
        putExtra("provider", provider.name)
    }
    startActivity(homeIntent)

}
```

My build.gradle(:app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.mpdw55.medic_app"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 30
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:17.4.4'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.3.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-auth:6.3.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'

}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Can someone help me ??

Comment: Why are you putting closing braces immediately after `addOnCompleteListener {` ?

Comment: I think that's the error. You're closing the brace before the if/else that's supposed to go inside the braces.

Comment: thanks for your comments, I already changed the braces of position, but the warning still apperaing

Comment: the warning still appears

Answer (score 0):

you should try to put the if(it.isSuccesfull){}else{} in between the brackets for the .addOnCompleteListener the result should be something

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
            .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditTest.text.toString(),
                passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {

       if (it.isSuccesful) {
            showHome(it.result?.user?.email?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)

        } else {
            showAlert()

        } }
```

And the error should be solved. You should also do the same for the sing in.

```
logInButton.setOnClickListener {
       if (emailEditTest.text.isNotEmpty() && passwordEditText.text.isNotEmpty()) {

           FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
               .signInWithEmailAndPassword(emailEditTest.text.toString(),
                   passwordEditText.text.toString()).addOnCompleteListener {

           if (it.isSuccesful) {
               showHome(it.result?.user?.email?:"", ProviderType.BASIC)

           } else {
               showAlert()

           }}
```